# OnTopReplica Alternative for Mac OS X

Tags: mac, afloat

Does anyone know an alternative to [OnTopReplica](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/ontopreplica) that will work on OS X?

OnTopReplica basically clones a window using Windows 7's DWM feature and then lets the user crop it and keep it always on top. Right now, I just use [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) to keep a window on top, but something like this would be much better (especially the "cropping" part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my search for an OnTopReplica alternative for OS X, I came across "[Duplicate Windows](http://www.fabiancanas.com/Projects/DuplicateWindows/)" by Fabián Cañas. It functions similarly to it, though not perfectly. It is open source though; maybe someone can help enhance it!

I submitted the application to [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/duplicate-windows/) as well.